# É viável utilizar copyBulk com datatable para carga de dados em SGBD?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datatable

Passei por uma experiência em efetuar grande carga de dados a partir de arquivo texto, que necessitava ser criticada antes de gravar no BD. Utilizei DataTable com copybulk. Percebi que a carga dos dados no DataTable e posteriormente no BD eram rápidas. Recebi críticas a respeito do uso do DataTable. A vantagem do DataTable é a possibilidade de criação de índices e cria-lo idêntico à tabela do BD.

Comment: Que críticas você recebeu? Você está questionando a viabilidade de utilizar o copyBulk em qual sentido?

Comment: ´Não questiono o uso do copyBulk. É muito eficiente e rápido. A  crítica que recebi é que datatable á uma tecnologia ultrapassada e que é lenta. No meu caso a performance foi muito boa (cerca de 100.000 registros). O que me incomoda é que os padrões existentes muitas vezes são vistos como uma lei, e quem não a utilizar pode ser considerado um "marginal". Adoro padrões, mas não me deixo escravizar por nenhum deles. Afinal foram desenvolvidos por profissionais como nós.

Comment: Bem, entendo muito pouco de C#, e portanto não sou qualificado para responder. Entretanto a sua pergunta parece mais um desabafo do que uma pergunta procurando uma resposta. Não consegui entender que tipo de informações você espera ver em uma resposta. Tente editar ela para deixar mais claro qua é especificamente a sua dúvida e o que é que você espera ver na resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é viável, desde que atenda e resolva o seu problema em específico.

Como em todo tipo de software, não há apenas uma única linguagem ou uma única tecnologia ou um único padrão para implementar software. Software deve ser entendido como uma solução para um determinado problema. A linguagem, tecnologia ou padrão vai depender de uma série de variáveis, como por exemplo: Necessidades do cliente, infra estrutura do cliente, custos com hardware e licenciamento, mão de obra e conhecimento disponível em sua região, tempo de vida do software etc.

Para um programa simples de importação de dados que será utilizado para migrar de um sistema pra outro ou de um banco de dados para outro, se for utilizado uma única vez e depois descartado, o padrão de design utilizado ou a linguagem ou bibliotecas não importará muito pois não é algo que você dará manutenção no futuro. Então, resolvendo o seu problema hoje, implemente da maneira que funcionar e atender bem. Mas caso esse programa seja utilizado frequentemente, e haja necessidade de mantê-lo, modificá-lo ou evoluí-lo, pense melhor nessa questão, pois outras pessoas terão de mexer no código, então é bom que utilize um padrão mais atual, pois é raro encontrar no mercado profissionais que trabalhem com tecnologias mais antigas. Procure entrar em consenso com seu time ou sua equipe.